# How to correct configuration for firewalld and docker/nginx?

Tags: docker, nginx, centos7, cloudflare, firewalld

I have a CentOS 7 server which was running happily for 600+ days until it was rebooted recently, after which incoming web requests were receiving HTTP523 (Origin Is Unreachable) error codes (via Cloudflare, if that makes a difference?) unless I stopped the `firewalld` service. Things run fine without `firewalld`, but I'd rather not leave it disabled!

I've tried stopping `docker` and `firewalld` and restarting them in various sequences, but the same `523` error occurs unless I stop `firewalld`.

`/var/log/firewalld` contains a few warnings that might help:

- `WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -D FORWARD -i br-8acb606a3b50 -o br-8acb606a3b50 -j DROP' failed: iptables: Bad rule (does a matching rule exist in that chain?).`
- `WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -D FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j DROP' failed: iptables: Bad rule (does a matching rule exist in that chain?).`
- `WARNING: AllowZoneDrifting is enabled. This is considered a n insecure configuration option. It will be removed in a future release. Please consider disabling it now.`
- `WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -t nat -D PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER' failed: iptables v1.4.21: Couldn't load target 'DOCKER':No such file or directory`
- `WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -t nat -D PREROUTING' failed: iptables: Bad rule (does a matching rule exist in that chain?).`
- `WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -t nat -D OUTPUT' failed: iptables: Bad rule (does a matching rule exist in that chain?)`
- `WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -t nat -F DOCKER' failed: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.`

I've found seemingly conflicting advice around the place regarding any manual configuration/commands required:

1. [`firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=trusted --add-interface=docker0` on a CentOS forum](https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?t=74270)
2. [`firewall-cmd --zone=trusted --remove-interface=docker0 --permanent` on the offical Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/network/iptables/#integration-with-firewalld) -- surely that's the opposite of the above?
3. [a bunch of manual `firewall-cmd` commands on a Docker github issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/35043#issuecomment-356036671) -- surely all of that isn't required?
4. this one looks promising -- [`nmcli`, `NetworkManager` and `firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=trusted --change-interface=docker0`](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/16137#issuecomment-271615192)

I don't fully understand where the `br-8acb606a3b50` interface comes from, or whether I need to do anything to configure it as well as `docker0` if I use a solution like `4.` above? It was all working fine automatically for years until the reboot!

Are some magic `firewalld` incantations now required (and why?!) or is there some way I can get the system to get back into the correct auto/default configuration it was in prior to rebooting?

```
$ docker -v
Docker version 20.10.5, build 55c4c88
$ firewall-cmd --version
0.6.3
$ firewall-cmd --get-zones
block dmz docker drop external home internal public trusted work
```

Comment: What is the CentOS minor version? There was a bug in 7.2, 7.3 which was fixed at some point after 7.4. Here is the explanation and possible fixes [1](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/16137#issuecomment-271615192) [2](https://github.com/firewalld/firewalld/issues/195#issuecomment-273266234)

Comment: `/etc/redhat-release` says `CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)`

Comment: Strange then. The symptoms look similar to those described in the solution 4. When running Docker along with `firewalld` it should add all its interfaces ('docker0', 'br-8acb606a3b50', etc.) to the 'docker' firewalld zone. You do have the zone but somehow there is still no DOCKER chain in iptables ('No chain/target/match by that name'). Let's see where is the 'docker0' interface: `firewall-cmd --get-zone-of-interface=docker0`

Comment: `firewall-cmd --get-zone-of-interface=docker0`: `no zone`

Comment: Okey, two last things: `nmcli connection show docker0 | grep zone` and `ls /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-*`. If the first returns nothing and in the second you see no `docker0`, I suggest you with the solution 4.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230358/discussion-between-drmeers-and-anemyte).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To recap the [chat investigation](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230358/discussion-between-drmeers-and-anemyte), this particular problem wasn't related to Docker and containers. The problem was in `firewalld` not having rules for `NGINX` running as a proxy for containers on the host. The solution was to add permanent firewalld rules for HTTP and HTTPS traffic:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=http
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=https
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

Warning messages like this one:

> WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -D FORWARD -i br-8acb606a3b50 -o br-8acb606a3b50 -j DROP' failed: iptables: Bad rule (does a matching rule exist in that chain?)

... can appear during normal operation, when Docker attempts to delete a rule without checking its existence first. In other words, containers can be running smoothly even when there are warnings like this.

Answer (score 1):

I had some similar problems with Podman and for me i had to upgrade from Debian 9 to Debian 10 in order to fix it, because of the way firewalld handles iptables vs nftables.

Comment: I can't imagine this issue would be impossible to solve without upgrading OS!

Comment: @DrMeers In my opinion, you can consider updating the OS and check that is it solves your problem.

Comment: CentOS 7 end-of-life isn't until June 30, 2024